# Set up a KNN for a score

Tags: python, knn

I try to fill nan on the column "score" using a KNN (based on values from columns X_100g, Y_100g and Z_100g.

Here is my df:

```
Product_Name   brand   score    X_100g    Y_100g    Z_100g
PA              abc      a        40        45         na
PB              def      b        27        27          8
PC              ghi      na       78        na         56
PD              klm      c        na        29         29
PE              nop      b        57         3         76
PF              qrs      na       45        42         33
```

What I tried is :

```
imputer = KNNImputer(n_neighbors=5)
dataknn = imputer.fit_transform(data.filter("score"))
```

It seems that it doesn't work due to an error:

> ValueError: at least one array or dtype is required

Can anyone help me solve that?

Thanks!

I tried to change my initial code for:

```
imputer = SimpleImputer(strategy = "most_frequent")
dataimputed = imputer.fit_transform(data.filter(["score"]))
```

As a result I have the following error: "ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Mistake 1:**

`df.filter('score')` returns an empty dataframe.

This is because Pandas expects a list-like object as the `'items'` parameter (i.e., a list of the names of the columns you want to select), refer [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html). However, you are supplying a `str`.

Do a `df.filter(['score'])`, or just a `df['score']` to extract the `'score'` column as a dataframe.

**Mistake 2:**

You are using `KNNImputer` with categorical variables, which is not possible as it works only on numeric data.

Instead, use `SimpleImputer` (or `IterativeImputer`) with the `'most_frequent'` or `'constant'` strategies – these work with categorical data.

If you really wish to use `KNNImputer`, first encode the `'score'` column, impute the null values and then convert back.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I modified my intial post to reflect your recommandations

Comment: `imputer = SimpleImputer(strategy='most_frequent', missing_values='na')` seems to work correctly by replacing all the `'na'` strings with `'b'`. Are you sure the error isn't originating from somewhere else?